# Optimal Graphs/ Vertex Covers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would one display that the total size of an optimal vertex cover of a graph with the total amount of vertices given as n, is n-1?

This makes no logical sense to me, can someone show how you would solve this?

I understand the cover is just a handful pick essentially of vertices which covers all edges? So how could you get n-1..?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you want to build a graph for which the minimum vertex cover is always $n-1$?

Comment: How about $K_n$?

Comment: (Gallai, 1959?) Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and let $\alpha(G)$ be the size of any maximal independent set of vertices of $G$ and let $\tau(G)$ be the size of any minimum vertex cover. Then $$n=\alpha(G)+\tau(G).$$ For any graph $G$, $\alpha(G)\ge 1$, so $\tau(G)\le n-1$.